# Get the property name of caller to the extension method

Tags: c#, extension-methods

I have created an extension method:

```
public static class Validation
        {
            public static bool ValidateEMail(this String str)
            {
            return Regex.Match(str, @"\w+([-+.]\w+)*@\w+([-.]\w+)*\.\w+([-.]\w+)*").Success;
            }

         }
```

I can call this method as:

```
bool result = EMailId.ValidateEMail()
```

My Question is:
Can I get the property name of the caller of this extension method within my extension method so that I can do additional operation on that property name? 
**In this case, can I get the name "EmailId" within "ValidateEMail"**

Thanks

Comment: Make it an `Expression<Func<string>>`. You can inspect expression body and for trivial expressions is pretty easy.  You will use it as `ValidateEmail(() => Emailid) `. Even better with c# 6 static usings.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Thanks. Will try this.